# Why is it mandatory to specify the module name at start of source file?

Tags: file, haskell, module

GHC insist that the module name has to equal the file name. But if they are the same, then why does a Haskell compiler need both? Seems redundant for me. Is this only a language design mistake?

Beside the inconvinience it also raises the problem that if I want to use 2 libraries that accidentially have the same top module name, then I can not disambiguate simply by renaming the folder of one of them. What is the idiomatic solution to this problem?

Comment: [Package-qualified imports](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#package-imports)

Comment: Redundancy is not a real problem—there is only one module name per module, and it typically takes up a minuscule fraction of the file. Name clashes are a real problem (occasionally), but your approach doesn't really solve them.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The Haskell language specification requires that modules are started by a module header, and it does not mention files - it leaves total freedom for the implementing compilers regarding files. So the Haskell language lacks the ability to express where files containing modules are. Because of this some compilers [including the most important one: GHC] use a simple solution : the name of the module must match the path from an include directory to the file. This introduced the redundancy.

To avoid the redundancy, the compilers could drop the requirement in the language specification to start each module by a header. However they chose not to do this simply for the sake of confirming to the specification. Perhaps a GHC language extension could do this, but currently there is no such extension.

So the problem is a language design mistake, and lives on as legacy.

To combat possible name collisions among independent libraries, GHC extension [Package-qualified imports](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#package-imports) seems the best way.

Comment: Carl, thank you for your answers, they were the ones from where i understood the situation. So i voted them up. However I could not accept your one as the answer, because your answer sounds like there is no problem and everything is fine, which clearly is not the situation.

Comment: Note: I insist that this is a language design mistake. The mistake is either the lack of file path specifications in the language from the beginnings or the avoiding of the modification of the language now when the module headers are already redundant.

Answer (score 8):

The Haskell language specification doesn't talk about files. It only talks about modules and their syntax. So there's clearly no language design mistake.

The GHC compiler (and many others) chose to follow a pattern of one module per file, and searching for modules in files with matching names. Seems like a decent strategy to me. Otherwise you'd need to provide the compiler with some mapping from module name to file name or an explicit list of every file in use.

Comment: That's indeed a decent strategy but then why do you need then to name the module within the file ?

Comment: Because the language spec says you have to name the module.  It doesn't know about files.  And it's not even the case that the file name is equal to the module name in ghc, the file name is only equal to the last part of the dotted module name.

Comment: @mb14 I feel like you're coming from languages that aren't defined by specifications, like PHP, Ruby, or Python. Unlike those, Haskell actually has a specification - one that predates GHC. GHC is following the specification here, not creating it.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand what is the purpose of this specications. As the OP said, it's redundant. So what are the benefit of the 'module A where` compare to nothing ?

Comment: @mb14 The specification says that modules are identified by a module header that gives the name of the module and an optional export list. It says nothing about files. The redundancy was introduced by GHC to allow easily finding the file containing a module. GHC chose not to violate the spec by removing the requirement of having a module header.

Comment: This is similar to C++. `#include <header>` does not necessarily specify a file name. It's up to the compiler vendor.

Comment: The lang spec does not solve the file search problem, which forces the compilers to use a solution which makes the module headers [a part of the lang spec] redundant. This does seem to me a [language design] mistake.

Comment: C++ "#include" corresponds to Haskell "import", not to Haskell "module .. where". Also, in C++ one does not need to specify the filename inside the file. However, there still is some similarity to C++, but to namespaces [not "#include"]. In C++ the namespace of a library has to be specified by the library itself, which makes 2 libraries with accidentially equal names not simultaniously usable - and there is no solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that one of the big reasons is that you *don't* always want the module name to be path to the file appended with the file name.  This is the same as with Java, C#, and many other languages that prefer an explicit namespace declaration in the source code, explicit is better than implicit in many cases.  It gives the programmer maximum control over their filenames without tying it to the filename only.

Imagine that I was a Japanese Haskell programmer, and my OS used Japanese characters for file names.  I can write my source code using Japanese characters where possible, but I also want to export an API that uses ASCII characters.  If module name and filename had to be identical, this would be impossible and would make it very difficult for people in other countries to use my library.

And as @chi has pointed out, if you have two packages with conflicting module names (a very rare occurrence in my experience), you can always use package-qualified imports.

Comment: Whic control over the filename do you have, as IT HAS TO BE the same as the module name ?

Comment: @mb14 `echo module NotTest where" > Test.hs`; `ghc --make Test.hs` seems to work.  Do you have a source for your claim?

Comment: The source is in the OP question : "GHC insists that the module name has to equal the file name", which you didn't contradict, so I assumed you took this assumption as true. Anyway, how can you import 'NotTest' ? If you can't import or load it what's the point of giving it name ?

Comment: @mb14 Don't confuse what ghc does with what Haskell specifies.  Other Haskell implementations may very well allow the file name and module name to differ.  Or to have multiple modules in a file.  Or have a module spread over several files.  Or not have files at all.

Comment: @bheklilr, your simple command line works only because it is a sole file to be compiled [you explicely tell GHC where is the file], not one that has to be found by GHC from a module import statement in another file.